# I am getting the folllowing error: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning

Tags: python-3.x

I am getting the folllowing error: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning while using Python Matplotlib.pyplot.
The main objective of this program was to color the figure into grey color.

The code:

```
import openpyxl as xl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

print("")
print("Test")
print("")
print("")

wb = xl.load_workbook("test.xlsx")
sheet = wb.active

lsta = []
lstb = []
def func(col, lst):
    sp = list(sheet[col])
    for e in sp:
        lst.append(e.value)

func("A", lsta)
func("B", lstb)

result = [x - y for x, y in zip(lsta, lstb)]
e = max(result)
s = min(result)

index = list((f"M{e}" for e in range(1, len(result)+1)))

fig = plt.figure(facecolor='grey')

plt.bar(index, result, color="green", edgecolor="purple", linewidth=2)
ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_facecolor("black")

for e in result:
    print(e)
plt.show()
```

Comment: A python warning is not the same thing as an error. If you're truly getting an error, please provide the traceback

Comment: A deprecation warning simply says that a function or method that you used might not work in later versions of the module / Python. This doesn't actually throw an error, and your code should work. It's simply _warning_ you that something might go wrong in the future, since the function you used is not being updated anymore (deprecated).